# Add event listener to canvas using for loop not returning correct index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add an event listener to dynamic canvas. Instead of manually writting event listener for each canvas I used a for loop. The problem is when I click at canvas1 it returns id 3. It's suppose to be 1.

```
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = []
var totalCanvas = 2

for(var i=1;i<=totalCanvas;i++){
    canvas[i] = document.getElementById('canvas'+i);
    canvas[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { onMouseDown(e,i) }, false);
}

function onMouseDown(e,i){
    console.log('ID'+i) //returning 3
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because by the time you raise the `mousedown` event the loop has completed and `i` is always at the last value set in the loop.

One way to fix this would be to wrap the event handler in a closure to retain the state of the `i` value:

```js
var canvas = []
var totalCanvas = 2

for (var i = 1; i <= totalCanvas; i++) {
  canvas[i] = document.getElementById('canvas' + i);
  (function(i) { 
    canvas[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      onMouseDown(e, i)
    }, false)
  })(i);
}

function onMouseDown(e, i) {
  console.log('ID' + i) //returning 3
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#canvas1 { background-color: #C00; }
#canvas2 { background-color: #0C0; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

A better way would be to select the `canvas` elements and loop through them, assigning the event handler to them directly and using the `index` argument of `forEach()` to get the index.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');

canvas.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    onMouseDown(e, i + 1)
  }, false)
});

function onMouseDown(e, i) {
  console.log('ID' + i)
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#canvas1 {
  background-color: #C00;
}

#canvas2 {
  background-color: #0C0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var canvas = [];
  var totalCanvas = 2;
  
  for(var i=1;i<=totalCanvas;i++){
      let a = i;
      canvas[i] = document.getElementById('canvas'+i);
      canvas[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {       onMouseDown(e,a) }, false);
  }
  
  function onMouseDown(e,x){
      console.log('ID'+x) //returning 3
  }
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#canvas1 { background-color: #C00; }
#canvas2 { background-color: #0C0; }
```

```html
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```